# Processing many large files

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a directory containing a large number of large compressed text files (where a "large file" is one that doesn't fit in the heap once decompressed).

I have a reduce operation that I want to apply on each file. The operation needs to process lines in order, and produces a small result, of type `A`.

How can I apply this operation on all files in my directory and obtain an `RDD` of type `(Path,A)`?

In other words, I'm looking for something similar to:

```
sc.wholeTextFiles(dir).mapValues(operation)
```

...but where the files do not need to be stored in memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they are gzipped, you will get one partition per file, so you can get away with something like:

```
sc.textFile(dir).mapPartitions(it => it.reduce(operation))
// mapPartitions gives you an iterator for each file, 
// apply the reduce operation on this.
```

Comment: Thanks, this does work. It is a little unsatisfactory to be relying on the file/partition mapping though, but like you say, I "can get away" with it for now.